# Почему блок перекрывает заголовок?

Tags: bootstrap

Помогите понять, почему блок наезжает на заголовок H1.

Сайт сверстан на Bootstrap 3. Тут на всю ширину:

[image: Скриншот 1]

Уменьшаем ширину, тут нормально:

[image: Скриншот 2]

Верхнее меню перескочило, так и должно быть:

[image: Скриншот 3]

Верхнее меню "схлопнулось", так и должно быть:

[image: Скриншот 4]

А вот такого быть не должно. Верхний белый блок должен стать больше по высоте и черное меню должно оказаться ниже, чтобы синий заголовок не перекрывался:

[image: Скриншот 5]

Еще хуже:

[image: Скриншот 6]

При раскрытии верхнего меню оно перекрывается синим заголовком:

[image: Скриншот 7]

Скажите, почему верхний белый блок остался по высоте тем же что и раньше и что сделать, чтобы он увеличился на высоту синего заголовка и чтобы заголовок ничего не перекрывал?

Вот здесь выложил: http://xenglish.ru/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У лого и заголовка стоит ограничение по высоте. Попробуйте перекрыть его вот так:

```
.navbar-brand {
  height: auto;
}
```

На моём экране после этого всё встало на свои места - и заголовок из под лого выбрался, и высота блока увеличилась.

Comment: @Stanislav Khatsko   Вот, проверьте пожалуйста. http://glebkema.ru/tasks/so-ru-518475/

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо.

Comment: У меня пока недостаточно рейтинга чтобы принять ваш ответ как лучший.

Answer (score 0):

css - @media изучите, там где сужения экрана происходит, там и меняйте размеры текста и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Такое происходит потому что bootstrap использует фиксированную высоту заголовка. Не используйте bootstrap для верстки заголовков, если не нравится такое поведение.

Comment: Нужно было всего лишь переопределить .navbar-brand и выставить height: auto;

Comment: @StanislavKhatsko там потом другие глюки вылезут...

Comment: Например какие?